# Convert HTML tables to GFM

Tags: linux, document-converter, markdown, github

Is there a tool to convert tables in Web pages to [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/)?

Ideally it should work by copy and pasting the table.

I'm on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to convert a saved page - various flavours of markdown are supported and can be tailored.

Comment: That sounds great, Steve! Are you using it yourself? Are you satisfied with its quality/processing speed/ease-of-use? +1 in advance for some more details :)

Comment: I invite you try it with [this](http://aylien.com/text-api-doc#pricing) table because I'm not getting anything usable.

Comment: Not sure what is going wrong there - shame.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I've found is

1. Copy and paste the text into a LibreOffice Calc or Excel spreadsheet. It should automatically recognize the table.
2. Copy and paste the table into http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables using File > Paste table data, then *Copy to Clipboard*.